# Contact back to somebody?

Tags: grammaticality

Here is the scenario. A colleague who is working remotely is working on a review of my design for some work item. We came up with a comment several weeks ago but I just haven't got a chance to update the design document until today. Eventually I updated the design document and submitted it for review. But I also want to write an email to him to apologize for taking so long before contacting him again. So I want to start the mail with "Sorry for contacting you back so late. But...". My question is, is it proper to say "contact you back"?

Comment: No. it is not correct. _Sorry for replying so late_ would for example be better or _Apologies for the delayed response_

Comment: How about "Sorry for getting back to you late"? Because we didn't use the email to discuss the design before,  so i don't think "replying to him" is proper. Any comments?

Comment: See my update...

Answer (score 4):

I ran a search at [CoCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), [BNC](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=contact+you+back&mysubmit=Go) and [Google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=contact+you+back&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for "contact you back". The only hit I got was at BNC, which was for speech in 1992.

In conclusion, "contact you back" is not usual English. It is fine in informal, conversational contexts, but should not be used in formal circumstances.

"Contacting you back" resulted in zero hits on any of the corpuses.

It is not unusual to say you will do something back to someone, meaning you'll do something in response at a later time or date, e.g. *call you back* or *email you back*.

I'm not sure why *contact* does not seem to work in the same way. It could perhaps be to do with its general nature, i.e. it doesn't specify how the contacting will take place.

Comment: I had no doubt you would not find anything. Perhaps Indian English with their "revert" could create such a construct but I could not imagine anyone else :)

Comment: It seems unwarranted (and wrong) to say that “contact you back” is   “fine in informal, conversational contexts”.

Comment: @jwpat7 given that it is used in those contexts, it makes sense to me.

Comment: So I guess I should have started with "Sorry for contacting you again so late. But..." Is this perfect?

Answer (score 2):

*Contact back to someone* indeed is not common English usage.

Instead, consider using any of the following:

> Sorry for my tardy/late reply/response...
>
> Sorry for not getting back to you earlier/sooner...
>
> Sorry for getting back to you (that) late...
>
> Sorry for not replying/responding to you earlier/sooner...